# InvalidToken error when accessing S3 from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have an AWS Lambda function which executes C++ code that needs to read from S3.

When I use Python to read from S3 within the same Lambda function, it works fine. When the C++ tries to read the same document I get the following error:

> GetObject error: InvalidToken Unable to parse
>
> The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.

Since the Python code is able to access the document I think my IAM permissions are set up correctly between Lambda and S3. I've confirmed that the access key, secret key, and session token environment variables are available to the C++ code. I'm not sure why it is getting this error from C++ but not from Python. Any ideas?

For reference, here is my Python code, which works fine:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)
obj.get()['Body'].read()
```

And the relevant C++ code, which produces the error:

```
Aws::SDKOptions options;
Aws::InitAPI(options);
Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client;

Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectRequest object_request;
object_request.WithBucket(bucket_name).WithKey(key_name);

auto get_object_outcome = s3_client.GetObject(object_request);

Aws::FStream jsonFile;
if (get_object_outcome.IsSuccess())
{
    jsonFile.open(key_name.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    jsonFile << get_object_outcome.GetResult().GetBody().rdbuf();
    std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "GetObject error: " <<
        get_object_outcome.GetError().GetExceptionName() << " " <<
        get_object_outcome.GetError().GetMessage() << std::endl;
}

Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);
```

I've also tried passing the credentials into the client directly, but still get the InvalidToken error:

```
const char* access_key = std::getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID");
const char* secret_key = std::getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY");
const char* session_token = std::getenv("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN");

Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials creds(access_key, secret_key, session_token);
Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client(creds);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve this. The problem is a combination of using AWS GovCloud and the C++ SDK, as mentioned at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/issues/365.

The solution is to manually set the `region` and `endpointOverride` of the `S3Client`, like so:

```
Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration config;
config.region = "us-gov-west-1";
config.endpointOverride = "s3-us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com";
Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client(config);
```

Hopefully this saves somebody else a week of heartache.